# PHP returns multiple strings

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to build a login page for my forums using Apache and MySQL XAMPP Databases, But it returns the echo string multiple times, I know it goes through all of the rows in the database checking if it's true or not it returns it as "Invalid Username or Password!" until it Finds the correct login information then returns "Welcome" Might be.

```
while($rows = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    //echo $rows;
    if($name==$rows[1]) {
        if($pass==$rows[2]) {
            echo "Welcome!";
        }
    }
    else if ($name!==$rows[1]) {
        echo "Invalid Username or Password!";
        if($pass!==$rows[2]) {
            echo "Invalid Username or Password!";
        }
    }
    $row = $row + 1;
}
```

Here is my Output:

> Invalid Username or Password!Invalid Username or Password!Invalid
>   Username or Password!Invalid Username or Password!Welcome!

How is it done so it returns just the one that is incorrect and correct strings?.

Comment: $row has a integer type but you are using it as a array. EDIT: The last line of code you do $rows = $row + 1. "$row" is never a variable change it to "$rows". So it should be $rows = $rows +1

Comment: Don't use the mysql library use mysqli as mysql is depreciated.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Answer (score 3):

I'm going about this from a different perspective. First of all the `mysql_*` extension is deprecated in as of PHP 5.5.0 and it's use is discouraged.

The next thing is I think you're going the wrong way about this. Why loop through the entire table for credentials when you can just check if there is a record with that username and that password? This is highly inefficient.

```php
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? && password = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $name, $pass);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->close();

// we found a record so the username and password match
if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
   echo 'Welcome!';
// no records so either the username or password doesn't match
} else {
  echo 'Invalid Username or Password!';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep your code outside loop for return one row

```
$rows = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    //echo $rows;
    if($name==$rows[1]) {
        if($pass==$rows[2]) {
            echo "Welcome!";
        }
    }
    else if ($name!==$rows[1]) {
        echo "Invalid Username or Password!";
        if($pass!==$rows[2]) {
            echo "Invalid Username or Password!";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
use simple code

$sql=mysql_query("select * from `admin_details` where admin_email='$email' and admin_pass='$pass'");
 
if (mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
    echo "Welcome!";
} else {
    echo "Invalid Username or Password!";
}
```